# Copy past point-of-time of azure DB to new DB?

Tags: azure-sql-database, restore

I accidently deleted a few rows of data in an azure SQL database.

Problem is, I can't roll back the database back to before the delete, since it is used and tons of other changes had been made.

Is there a way to make a (temporary) copy of a past point in time of the DB to some other DB, local or in Azure?
There are no storage backups since the DB long exceeds the 4GB size limit for those.

Something like `CREATE DATABASE TempRestore AS COPY OF MainDb IN POINT OF TIME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Restore option on the database blade as shown below to restore a copy of the database with a new database name using a point-in-time backup of the database.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a new database from a point-in-time backup of any database you have. While creating the new database, you make a click on Additional Settings table, then click on Backup then select a backup from the combo box.

[image]

Comment: Duh, thats so obvious but it didn't occur to me that restore might create a new DB

Comment: With SQL Server we can restore and replace an existing database but with Azure SQL a restore creates a new database. Thanks for accepting the answer.